# subview not clickable in UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, custom-view

I'm trying to embed a custom view in UIViewController. But when displayed, it's not clickable since it's out of the UIView frame.

[image: storyboard screenshot]

viewDidLoad:

```
@IBOutlet var theVC_InVC_Test: UIView!

@IBOutlet var TableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    TableView.delegate = self
    TableView.dataSource = self

    func embed(_ viewController:UIViewController, inView view:UIView){
        viewController.willMove(toParent: self)
        viewController.view.frame = view.bounds
        view.addSubview(viewController.view)
        self.addChild(viewController)
        viewController.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
    embed(sidemenutest1(), inView: theVC_InVC_Test)

}
```

sidemenutest1 UIViewController:

```
func popItOver(){
    let PopOverVC = UIStoryboard(name:"Main",bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CoinsPopUp") as! CoinsPopUpViewController
    self.addChild(PopOverVC)
    PopOverVC.view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    self.view.addSubview(PopOverVC.view)
    PopOverVC.didMove(toParent: self)
}

@IBAction func storeAction(_ sender: Any) {
    popItOver()
}
```

[image: simulator output]

It's displayed fine, but it's not clickable... When I tried to click the subview buttons, the TableView is clicked and not the subview.

Comment: “it's not clickable since it's out of the UIview frame.” Yes, a view outside its superview is not clickable. If you know that, what is the question?

Comment: how to solve it. i don't want the side menu view to fit more that the given area but the pop up must came in the middle.

Comment: Then don’t make the pop up a subview of the side menu. Or change the way hit testing works.

Comment: it has to be this way, what is your recommendation to solve this issue.

Comment: No it doesn’t “have to be this way”.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add the popover menu as a container view controller. It should be presented from the controller as a modal view controller instead and set its background view color to be the translucent gray color.

Comment: could you write a sample code.i'm not sure how to do it since the button is in another view

Comment: The button is inside a view controller somewhere. Present on that view controller like you would any other view controller: `self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`